# Automatic creation of voice mailboxes with uploaded greeting

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am currently creating a user facing web app and service (Using Bubble.io) for leaving voice messages for my customers from people dialing in from their phones to a specific number they have been provided. I am using Twilio for the voice backend.

Essentially, for each customer I have on my Bubble app, I need to assign them a phone number that people can call, upload a unique greeting message (audio file), and then assign this as the voice greeting before sending the caller straight to voicemail.

I've managed to use the API to provision Twilio phone numbers and to access voicemail recordings. I have also managed to upload some greetings as Twilio assets, but this is where I am getting a bit lost.

What is the best way of implementing this solution in Twilio? Should I be making a function? Or can I do this in Twilio Studio? I was originally planning to control all of this via the REST API from my own app, but it looks like for some of the requirements I have, I will need to rely on developing the Twilio side more.

Please see attached image that gives a rough account setup process and end-user journey. The greyed boxes are where I really need some guidance on the best methods to implement this.

Thanks in advance!

[Account setup & end-user journey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g182D.png)

Comment: The user journeys you described are totally achievable. Much of what you have outlined will require either a Twilio Function or hosting your web service that returns Twiml. For the uploading of the audio file, that can be hosted as a Twilio Asset or in any publicly accessible endpoint like an Azure Blob (not just as an Asset). I suggest starting by breaking the project down into iterations such as get a working "user calls and leaves a voicemail" then adding a feature to allow user to add their own customized voicemail greeting then add a feature that allows a new user to provision an account.